# Blender on Thinkpad x61 Good/Bad?

Tags: installation

What would peoples thoughts be, running blender on a Thinkpad  x60 / x61 if I went ahead and bought one?
the screen shot shows some specs.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: What do you want to do (Modeling, Rendering, Compositing etc.)?

Comment: Questions about hardware are considered off topic here, and answers to this are subjective and very opinion based

Answer (score 1):

Please see minimum Blender requirements:

https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Your spec does not pass them. There you can also find the optimal/recommended configuration.

Comment: i think its just the ram that doesn't pass but that can be upgraded?

Comment: Im not sure what think pad from the x series (220x and going back) would fit the specifications for blender my I please get your opinion ? Many thanks!

Comment: this is confusing because this guy got blender running on the x60? .. How?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EnvzZas-0s

Comment: also does i5 2nd gen cover the recomened dual core. Is i5 better? Im not sure ? many thanks

Comment: It's not about if you can get it to run, it's more about if you can use it. You should aim for the recommended spec. i5 is definitely better than core2duo M. Please see some hardware benchmarks.